# Camera does not follow player

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, render, game-development

I use libgdx   have one player which moves in **x** direction from left to right. Now I want the camera to follow it (like in  Flappy Bird for example).

What happen is that the player go out off screen when it reaches the right border of screen  and the camera don't follow him.

I have tried following options but none of them worked:

- `camera.position.set(player.getX(), camera.position.y, 0);`
- `camera.position.set(player.getX(), 0, 0);`
- `Vector3 vector3= camera.unproject(new Vector3(player.getX(), 0f, 0f));
  player.setX(vector3.x);`

I know that this question already exists on SO but none answer works in this case. Maybe I miss something important that i don't know.

---

The code:

*Game.java class*

```
  public class Game extends com.badlogic.gdx.Game implements   ApplicationListener {
  public static Vector2 VIEWPORT = new Vector2(320, 480);
  public static int WIDTH;
  public static int HEIGHT;


@Override
public void create() {
    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    // VIEWPORT = new Vector2(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
    VIEWPORT = new Vector2(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
 }

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

}
```

*GameScreen.java class*

```
import android.util.Log;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import java.util.Collections;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private OrthographicCamera camera;

private Player  player;
private PlayerInputHandler inputHandler1, inputHandler2;
private Sound sound;

FitViewport viewp;

public static int WIDTH;
public static int HEIGHT;


int width_spacing = 0;
int height_spacing = 0;


Stage stage;


Skin skin;


public GameScreen(Game game) {
   stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT));
    camera = (OrthographicCamera)  stage.getCamera();

     Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}


@Override
public void show() {
    resetGame();
}

public void resetGame() {


    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    width_spacing = Game.WIDTH / 24;
    height_spacing = Game.HEIGHT / 14;
    stage.clear();
      skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data2/uiskin.json"));

    prepareInputHandlers();
    prepare_stage();
}



public void addPlayer() {
    Texture texture = new Texture("player.png");
    player = new Player(texture);
    player.setPosition(Game.WIDTH / 2, Game.HEIGHT * 2 / 3);

    stage.addActor(player);
}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    if (delta > 1 / 60f) {
        player.setX(player.getX() + (4 * delta));


               camera.position.set(player.getX(), camera.position.y, 0);



    }

    update();


    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

private void update() {

    camera.update();


}

private void prepareInputHandlers() {

    inputHandler2 = new PlayerInputHandler(player, Input.Keys.LEFT, Input.Keys.RIGHT, Input.Keys.UP, Input.Keys.DOWN);
}


@Override
public void dispose() {


    sound.dispose();

    player.getTexture().dispose();
}




public void prepare_stage() {
     addPlayer();

    player.setWidth(64);
    player.setHeight(64);




}
@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 }
```

*Player.java class*

```
 import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

 public class Player extends com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image{

private Texture texture;


public Player(Texture texture) {
    super(texture);

  }
     public Texture getTexture() {
    return texture;
}
   @Override
   public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
   }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use stage's camera instead of creating your own. Change your GameScreen constructor like this:

```
    public GameScreen(Game game) 
    {
        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT));
        camera = (OrthographicCamera) stage.getCamera();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }
```

then in the **render** method set the camera position just like

```
    camera.position.set(player.getX(), camera.position.y, 0);
```

**before** camera.update() call

---

There is also something strange in your code - why you have **camera.position.set()** and setting player **x** in this condition:

```
    if (delta > 1 / 60f) //??
    {
        player.setX(player.getX() + (4 * delta));
        camera.position.set(player.getX(), camera.position.y, 0);
    }
```

I'm pretty sure you don't need this - but even if you need the

```
    camera.position.set(player.getX(), camera.position.y, 0);
```

should be out of if statement because what is happening now is that even if you are changing your player position (using keybord through **PlayerInputHandler** object) you **don't update camera position. Try to remove if statement or at least do something like

```
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (delta > 1 / 60f) 
        {
            player.setX(player.getX() + (100 * delta));
        }

        camera.position.set(player.getX(), camera.position.y, 0);
        update();

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }
```

last thing is that if your stage is empty (excluding player) when camera will start to follow player - you will see as player not moving at all :) Add someting more to stage

Comment: i am sorry but what is gameWorld object

Comment: all my code classes were written above and i don't know this object

Comment: I'm sorry I've copied it from mine old code and didn't change to **stage** - I edited it already

Comment: thanks but it didn't succeed for me it make from the begining the player almost static near the right border of screen and doesn't move

Comment: and what does your code look like now? Have you removed `unproject` and scond `player.setX`. If it is possible share your code for example using http://pastebin.com/

Comment: yes . i removed them of course and now  i use 
                
    if (delta > 1 / 60f) {
        player.setX(player.getX() + (4 * delta));


           camera.position.set(player.getX(), camera.position.y, 0);


         }

        camera.update();

Comment: please share whole Screen class (the game one) code or at least update question with it - it is hard to investigate the issue not seeing code... :)

Comment: thanks m.antkowicsz I  updated GameScreen.java class now